# How do I group a new column by categories based on another column?

Tags: google-sheets

I would like a formula to essentially do what the =countif "criteria" formula does; however, instead of a number of how many times "criteria" occurs I would like it to display the name of each person that has said "criteria". Please see below...

| Name (Column A) | Dietary Preference (Column B) |
| --- | --- |
| Tom | Regular Diet |
| Anna | Regular Diet |
| Julie | Pescatarian |
| John | Vegetarian |
| Emma | Regular Diet |
| Bob | Vegetarian |

I would like to convert the above table to look like the below table

| Vegetarians | Pescatarians | Regular Diet |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | Julie | Tom |
| Bob | ------------ | Anna |
| ----------- | ------------ | Emma |

Comment: Please share a link to a sample spreadsheet containing the sample source data in your post. Keeping in mind that the contributors here are all volunteers, it is much easier to *show* how to do this than to try to *tell* about it only; and that will require an accessible spreadsheet to test and leave solutions. Help us to help you by sharing a link.

Comment: THANK YOU ALL FOR YOUR HELP. I was able to finally figure it out, and instagram of all places. Here is what I did based on the below spreadsheet from ztiaa: =FILTER($A$2:$A$7,$B$2:$B$7=D2)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
={transpose(unique(filter(B2:B,B2:B<>"")));
index(transpose(split(flatten(query(
if(transpose(unique(filter(B2:B,B2:B<>"")))<>filter(B2:B,B2:B<>""),,
filter(A2:A,B2:B<>"")),,9^9))," ")))}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## Formula

###### Unsorted:

```
=MAP(TOROW(UNIQUE(B2:B),1), LAMBDA(diet,
  { diet; FILTER(A2:A,B2:B=diet) }))
```

###### Sorted

```
=MAP(SORT(TOROW(UNIQUE(B2:B),1)), LAMBDA(diet,
   { diet; SORT(FILTER(A2:A,B2:B=diet)) }))
```

###### Functions Used

[FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en)   [LAMBDA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718?hl=en)   [MAP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568985?hl=en)   [SORT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093150?hl=en)   [TOROW](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13187459?hl=en)   [UNIQUE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093198?hl=en)

## Explanation

1. To get the header row of diets,

   - `UNIQUE(B2:B)` gives you a [UNIQUE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093198?hl=en) list of items Column B
   - Placing that in the [TOROW](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13187459?hl=en) function transposes the list (column to row) and also removes the single blank row in one step: `TOROW(UNIQUE(B2:B),1)`
   - You can also place that in the [SORT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093150?hl=en) function to get the list in alphabetical order.
2. [MAP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568985?hl=en) is then used to pass each of the [UNIQUE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093198?hl=en) values into a  [LAMBDA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718?hl=en) function one-by-one
3. The  [LAMBDA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718?hl=en) function assigns each value to a variable named `diet` (arbitrarily chosen)
4. The  [LAMBDA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718?hl=en)'s formula is applied once for each value that is mapped in. And for each value, it returns a column of values that includes:

   - the current value of `diet` in the first row (header)
   - the subsequent rows are the results of a [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en) of Column A where Column B matches `diet` `FILTER(A2:A,B2:B=diet)`
   - The [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en) function can be placed in a [SORT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093150?hl=en) function if you want the names in alphabetic order.

You can optionally SORT the results by `diet` and/or `name`.  Here is the formula with both applied:

In this way, the formula automatically adjusts for additional rows as well as new diets.

<sub>**Unsorted Version**</sub>
[image: Animated screenshot of example formula unsorted]

<sub>**Sorted Version**</sub>
[image]